# Removing definition query in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, definition-query

I have created one script which set a defination query at certain location in script. 
I use `lyr.definitionquery = "some expression"`

After running the script i want to remove the definition query . But not getting any hint to do it.

Comment: It is the same lr.definitionQuery=""

Comment: I think `definitionquery` should be `definitionQuery`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just clear that property:

```
lyr.definitionQuery = None
```

`None` is the python for `NULL`, so making it = None will clear the query.

Comment: I always do it using ""

Comment: Yes you can also do it using `""` but I don't think it matters.  I've developed a habit of using Nulls over empty strings, but either works.

Answer (score 2):

I use an empty string to clear a definition query from a layer:

```
lyr.definitionQuery = ""
```